# Why am I getting "No app found to open URL" when trying to following SO links from Android Google search?

Tags: bug

When I search for a programming question from my Android device, I see the Google search results as usual including a ton of SO links, but if I try and click any of them I get a mysterious message "No app found to open URL".

- I have never used/installed the SO app.
- Clicking links to all other search results, on sites other than SO, works fine.
- This started a couple of days ago - or at least, that's when I first noticed it.
- I'm running Android 7.1.2 with Google app 7.1.29.21.arm64 (this is the app which provides the home screen search AFAIK)

[image: a google search for something technical, showing error message]

Comment: You've never installed the SE *or* the SO apps?

Comment: Nope, neither...

Comment: And other websites are working? The problem is only for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Are you able to copy the url? What protocol does it include?

Comment: This appears to be related to the Android Instant Apps that just released. It looks like SO is using Instant Apps for their links - http://stackoverflow.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Answer (score -4):

> Go to Settings > Apps​, tap Menu, and Reset All App Preferences.

Be aware that this will **remove your preference for all types of URLs**.

You could also install the SO app and navigate to it's settings, then clear just the SO apps preferences.

Comment: Of course, this will reset *all* your app preferences so use with caution. You may be better off installing the SO app and them removing it instead.

Comment: This is the only answer and it is quite proper. Why downvotes? *edits to mention this clears ALL*

Comment: I think you should put "remove your preference for all types of URLs" in bold style...